# How can one listen to an Azure Service Bus topic continuously?

Tags: azure, flask, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am running a service using Flask that, when a message is published on a topic, needs to trigger some code. I am unsure how to create the subscription name and all that, but I think I can hack at it. What I really don't know is how to be *constantly* listening to this topic and initiate the filters such that whenever a message that matches the criteria is met, it is always triggered. Is there some place I can be directed to?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use Azure Functions which will be triggered whenever a new message arrives in the topic:

```
import azure.functions as func

import logging
import json

def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message.')

    result = json.dumps({
        'message_id': msg.message_id,
        'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
        'content_type': msg.content_type,
        'expiration_time': msg.expiration_time,
        'label': msg.label,
        'partition_key': msg.partition_key,
        'reply_to': msg.reply_to,
        'reply_to_session_id': msg.reply_to_session_id,
        'scheduled_enqueue_time': msg.scheduled_enqueue_time,
        'session_id': msg.session_id,
        'time_to_live': msg.time_to_live,
        'to': msg.to,
        'user_properties': msg.user_properties,
        'metadata' : msg.metadata
    })

    logging.info(result)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python

Comment: Quick question about this solution: I've been looking and it seems like it requires the installation of a .NET framework. Is my assumption correct? Because if it is, I cannot do that.

Comment: no, you can use python sdk https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library